# More variables or one more dimension in array variable?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array

I heard that less dimensions is better, but is it worth it to change from method B (that i already use) to A?
What is the most optimal way of using array variables?

### Example code in C

```
Method A:
int var1[5][10][5][4];
int var2[5][10][5][4];
int var3[5][10][5][4];

Method B:
int var4[3][5][10][5][4];
```

Comment: Don't use raw arrays in c++ at all.

Comment: @user0042 `at all` is a bit overboard  IMO

Comment: context is important in this one. The memory usage is exactly the same and processor will be the same as well. I would definitely advise you to use some constants and better variable names because varN and 5, 10, 5, 4 will not tell anything to people reading your code.

Comment: raw arrays are part of the language for a reason, same goes for many other parts of the language. now it depends what type of project you are working on, or if you are a beginner how you learn best.

Comment: if you are looking at efficient arrays look here http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Array.html

Answer (score 2):

I think that if something is "better" or not depends a lot on the perspective, e.g. performance, readability, maintainability, consistency, and probably many more. There is probably no clear answer to your question, and every answer might be opinion based.

Anyway, you could "mix" both approaches, having separate variables that "view" slices of the "many-dimension"-array. Then you could pick the "best" approach for the respective context:

```
int main() {

    int var4[3][5][10][5][4] = { {{{1}}}, {{{2}}}, {{{3}}} };

    int (*var1)[5][10][5][4] = &var4[0];
    int (*var2)[5][10][5][4] = &var4[1];
    int (*var3)[5][10][5][4] = &var4[2];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`less dimensions is better` -- this is a very lame suggestion. The question is -- better for what?! As it was suggested in the comments, it all depends on the context. If you need it - you need it. There might not be a better way to express your algorithm.

There are questions of readability and performance. All arrays, no matter on hoe many dimensions, are allocated in memory linearly, so the compiler has to calculate the index. Performance comes from the fact that the compiler needs to do more complicated calculation than with single dimensional arrays. So, if you try to reduce the number of dimensions, you would probably move this calculations from the compiler to your code, most likely loosing performance and readability.

Now, if you, however can split it in independent variables for which you do not need any conditional logic to choose, do it. it will improve both. Do not aggregate unrelated variables into an array, it will reduce both.

I guess in your case, if `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` are independent, use them this way. If you need a loop to browse them, keep them in an array.